# Sum elements of an array over a given dimension

Tags: julia

I am quite new to Julia and learning the stuff by doing some projects.

I am stuck at at part of summing all matrix array by element.

I nave 2 * 2 * 1000 3-dimensional array. Basically, its about find the average variance-covariance matrix of 1000 samples. It iterates over the 1 to 1000.

I tried to use the Sum command but it gave me scalar.
I need [2,2,1] + [2,2,2] + [2,2,3] + ... [2,2,100] = (2 by 2 matrix)

Is there easy way without using loop?

Comment: `sum(x,dims=3)`. If any function `f` is not behaving as expected, try typing `?f` at the REPL for help. All functions in the base language are very well documented. Also, for future questions it is best to include [formatted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) code snippets.

Comment: I presume you are a MATLAB user. `sum`, `mean`, `std` in julia with a single parameter do not work over a default dimension, unlike MATLAB. If you do not specify the dimension, they work as if the array is of one dimension. If you `sum`, it sums up all the elements in the array. You need to specify the dimension in your case.

Answer (score 7):

As has already been pointed out in the comments, if you have a 3-dimensional array,

```
julia> x = rand(2,2,1000);
```

you can sum over any dimension by using (taken from `?sum`)

> `sum(A::AbstractArray; dims)`
>
> Sum elements of an array over the given dimensions.

In your case,

```
julia> result = sum(x, dims=3);
```

Note, however, that the result will still have 3 dimensions, as can be checked by `ndims` or by checking the type with `typeof`:

```
julia> ndims(result)
3

julia> typeof(result)
Array{Float64,3}
```

The reason for this behavior is type stability. The third dimension, which we summed over, will be a singleton dimension,

```
julia> size(result)
(2, 2, 1)
```

which can be dropped to give the desired 2x2 matrix result

```
julia> dropdims(result, dims=3)
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 510.444  503.893
 489.592  480.065
```

In total, `dropdims(sum(x, dims=3), dims=3)`.

**Remark (update)**

Loops are fast in Julia. So if it's not just for convenience you can get the result faster by using a loop implementation, e.g.

```
julia> function f(x::AbstractArray{<:Number, 3})
           nrows, ncols, n = size(x)
           result = zeros(eltype(x), nrows, ncols)
           for k in 1:n
               for j in 1:ncols
                   for i in 1:nrows
                       result[i,j] += x[i,j,k]
                   end
               end
           end
           result
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @btime dropdims(sum($x, dims=3), dims=3);
  7.034 μs (19 allocations: 592 bytes)

julia> @btime f($x);
  5.205 μs (1 allocation: 112 bytes)
```

Comment: I guess that in `f`, you should initialize `result` with something like `zeros(eltype(x), nrows, ncols)` instead (the uninititialized values `similar` produces are often like `6.94486e-310`, which makes one not notice the difference...)

Comment: Since you are defining this for `AbstractArray`s, you should use `for k in axes(x, 3)` etc. You could e.g. have an array with zero-based indices. In fact, I think one should always use `axes`, `eachindex`, etc.

Comment: Probably the improvement of the loop is not significant; testing with `n == 100000`, I measure 1.506 ms for the loop, and 953.397 μs for the one-liner (allocations are the same as in your measurements, but constant anyway).